# openstack nova goes down when ceph pool is set to have more than 1 pgs

Tags: openstack, ceph, openstack-nova

I have openstack connected to ceph cluster.
When i increase the pgs of the vms pool to be more than 1 and launch instance in openstack the instance is stuck on spawning state and nova compute container is going down.

If the vms pool pg-s are 1 or openstack is not connected to ceph i can create instances without problem.

Openstack version is bobcat
Ceph version is 18.2.0

Comment: I hope this is just a test cluster to play around with, because having only one PG is not a reasonable configuration. Can you show more details of your ceph cluster? `ceph osd tree`, `ceph osd pool ls detail`, `ceph osd crush rule ls` and `ceph osd crush rule dump <RULE>` for the vms pool.

Comment: @eblock could you please share place where i can put the result of the commands for you to see, because i cannot write it here as a comment, its too long

Comment: Just edit your question (and use code tags).